# Adding existing Node Js project to Existing .Net Solution

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, visual-studio, frontend

Updated. 
**Updated the question since it looks little ambiguous and not the answer i was looking for.**

We have a huge .NET application running on MVC and angular. It has multiple projects under the main solution. .[image: Looks something like this]

We also have a replica of that application in Node.js for front end developers. 
It looks something like this : [image]

What happens is  -  Front end developers make changes in Node js solution (like js or .less files or controller)  - make changes and move those changes to .Net solution which is the actual live project.

Off late - we have issues with developers working with two different solutions (Node and .NET) and keeping two copies of assets everywhere. 
We ultimately decided to combine them and bring the whole Node.js application into ours .NET Solution as 6th project.

Something like this [image]

**Wondering if anyone has previously done so - adding a .NET application with existing Node.js application. If so any pros and cons to consider.**
Some points to note - the Nodejs project and .Net project are completely independant of each other. The idea is  to consolidate the applications so that We can either run the .net application or UI application from single solution.

Eventually, we will consolidate all the assets to just one project so that - we dont have to do duplicates.

Also, would appreciate any links where I can see how to start merging these two applications.

Comment: It should not be a problem.. Expose the services from nodejs and consume from .Net. Even I have tried connecting to nodejs from c# using sockets i.e. tcp ip.

Comment: updated my question. hope its clear now

Comment: @NightMonger could you find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Arash We switched to VS 2017 where you could open both folders and solution. The set up is still the same but it is more like we use VS Code or sublime or any other editor for front end and vs 2017 for .net

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to look at [JavaScript Servcies](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices). [Building Single Page Applications on ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/).

Made for .NET Core, but you can run .NET Core on Full .NET Framework, which should make it easier to migrate to.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you have is, say, a production version in .NET and a development environment in node.js for developers which prefer that.
At the company I work for, we use AngularJS for our front end and .NET/Entity Framework back end and it works pretty well.
I'm not sure if you are integrating some sort of JavaScript back end in with it or not. Assuming you are going to stick with a .NET backend and a JavaScript heavy frontend, it should be fairly easy.
That being said, nothing in this career is truly "easy". I would recommend using an AngularJS frontend as it has seemingly endless functionality.

Some minor suggestions if you choose that route is to check out [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1).  great reference for writing AngularJS. Make sure you have consistent naming, especially in Visual Studio as AngularJS can be a little moody.
I prefer to bind values to the view when working on AngularJS, e.g.
`vm.title = "Data I want to bind";` in the view: `<h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>`
If that renders as `{{vm.title}}` instead of `Data I want to bind` you know something isn't working. I prefer catching it sooner rather than later.

Dependency Injection is another thing to be careful with, the style guide covers it as well.  Basically if you minify your AngularJS files and the minifier removes the information required for DI, your project will break. I've been down that rabbit hole a few times.

If you aren't intending on using AngularJS then forget I said anything. I was just exercising my fingers. I hope that helps shed a little light on your decision.

Comment: Sound like the question is about using server-side JavaSccript, not Angular.